# How to change text visible to user in the url to custom text in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, url

I am working on web application and my form name is `frmGenerateOrder` (standard naming convention) while running application in URL its coming `http://localhost:60529/frmGenerateOrder.aspx` as usual in asp.net

But I want show URL like `http://localhost:60529/OrderGeneration.aspx`

Is it possible ?

I tried:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>OrderGeneration</title>
```

But no changes its obvious. Can any one help me on same

Comment: The best thing for this is to use the IIS URL Rewrite module. https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: But need to host this application on server I don't have access to install such things on server. Can we achieve programmatically?

Comment: Then the only way is to create both pages and redirect from frmGenerateOrder to GenerateOrder.

Comment: why don't you change the file names?

Comment: because its standard naming convention i can't change form name

Comment: You could try it. Maybe the rewrite module is already installed on the server. https://ruslany.net/2009/04/10-url-rewriting-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: You can always ask the maintainer of the server to install it for you

Comment: I can't say that "frmMyWebPage" is any kind of standard here. I would just start naming your web pages as to what you want to appear. it starts to get really messy and hairy like if you spend all that time trying to create or manage the URL's to be anything different then what you choose for the web page name. I would right click on that web page in VS and choose re-name. You can go down some path of URL's re-write. I do of course recommend that you use friendly URL's, and thus you don't have nor see the .axpx suffix, but other then that I would not try to manage or change your URL's.